# Gzip CSS/JS Using OS X Terminal

Tags: macos, gzip

I am trying to use OSX Terminal to create gzip versions (.gz) of all css & js files in a folder. I found the following command, but when I cd to a test folder & then enter the command, it doesn't output anything & I would expect it to create a gzip copy in the folder next to the original file:

```
find . -regex ".*\(css\|js\)$" -exec bash -c 'echo Compressing "{}" && gzip -c --best "{}" > "{}.gz"' \;
```

What am I doing wrong?  Or does the command need to be modified?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that OS X version of `find` doesn't support extended regular expressions. Simple workaround would be to use logical `or` operator (`-o` option) like this:

```
find . \( -name "*\.js" -o -name "*\.css" \) -exec bash -c 'echo Compressing "{}" && gzip -c --best "{}" > "{}.gz"' \;
```

It will search for both file extensions and `exec` bash command for each found file.

**Update.**
I actually found out that your syntax will also work. You need to use `-E` option of `find` command to work with extended regular expressions. You may also need to enclose the pattern in double quotes.

```
find -E . -regex "".*\(css\|js\)$"" -exec bash -c 'echo Compressing "{}" && gzip -c --best "{}" > "{}.gz"' \;
```

From `find` man page:

```
-E   Interpret regular expressions followed by -regex and -iregex         
     primaries as extended (modern) regular expressions rather than basic
     regular expressions (BRE's).  The re_format(7) manual page fully
     describes both formats.
```

Comment: Thanks @baf - terminal commands are not my cup of tea - works great.